# How do I create a VBA code to copy information over if one piece of information matches another between sheets?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a large genealogical dataset which I exported to excel to enter in a specific programme to produce coefficients of relatedness. But the excel export is formatted differently to what the descent programme requires. I require my excel sheet to look like:

**Ego ID - Father ID - Mother ID - Sex**

But at the moment I have three sheets of the following in one workbook:

**Sheet 1: Ego ID - Surname - Give Name - Sex**

**Sheet 2: Family ID - Father ID - Mother ID**

**Sheet 3: Family ID - Child ID****

So I believe I need to code in VBA to do the following:

- If family ID in sheet 3 matches the family ID in sheet 2 then copy all the children in the family to the family ID row in sheet 2 after the mother ID (e.g. - **Family ID - Father ID - Mother ID - Child ID - CHILD ID**)
- Then would need to code that if the child ID in sheet 2 matches the Ego ID in sheet 1 then copy the relevant mother and father ID into the Ego ID row after Sex in sheet 1 (e.g. **Ego ID - Surname - Given Name - Sex - Father ID - Mother ID**)

Can anyone let me know if this is even possible? I have never coded in excel before and I have no idea where to start so any bit of help will be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `Can anyone let me know if this is even possible?` yes it is possible. `I have never coded in excel before` Um, this could be a problem then... What you are asking is something like "I don't know how to fly a plane but can anyone help me?" I can tell you to record macros, refer you to links which explain then Excel Object Model but is that really going to help you? I would suggest going through a free short online VBA tutorial to understand how excel works and then give the above a shot...

Comment: At the most, I can direct you [HERE](http://www.excel-vba.com/excel-vba-contents.htm) for the time being... And + 1 for taking out time to explain your question nicely :)

Comment: This is basic relational dataset processing. It would be vastly better suited to be done using queries in Access (or any other RDBMS system of your choice), in which case no coding would be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked for VBA code in Excel, but this is vastly better suited to processing in a relational database. Assuming you have Microsoft Access in your Office suite, do the following:

1. Create linked tables in Access to the three respective worksheets:

   - Sheet 1 as "People"
   - Sheet 2 as "Families"
   - Sheet 3 as "Children"
2. The following query will give you your result:

   ```
   SELECT
       People.[Ego ID]
     , Families.[Father ID]
     , Families.[Mother ID]
     , People.Sex
   FROM  
   ( Families INNER JOIN Children
       ON Families.[Family ID] = Children.[Family ID]
   ) INNER JOIN People
       ON Children.[Child ID] = People.[Ego ID]
   ```

Comment: Dear Joshua, Thanks for your wonderful advice - I haven't used access before (hence the delay in replying) and didn't realise how much of an error that was!! I ended up creating three tables as you said, connecting their relationships and then simply created an excel report! I was unsure how to do a query initially but just explored the programme and found  making a report did the same job I wanted. My coefficients are currently computing so thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Excel built-in VLOOKUP function and not even use VBA.